# How to obtain raws that have a datetime greater than specific datetime?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to obtain only those raws in Spark DataFrame `df` that have a datetime greater than `2017-Jul-10 08:35`. How can I do it?

I know how to extract rows corresponding to specific datetime, e.g. `2017-Jul-10`, however I don't know how to make the comparison, i.e.e greater than `2017-Jul-10 08:35`.

```
df = df.filter(df("p_datetime") === "2017-Jul-10")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `p_datetime` is in custom date format so you need to convert to proper date format to compare,

Below is a simple example to represent your problem

```
val df = Seq(
  ("2017-Jul-10", "0.26"),
  ("2017-Jul-9", "0.81"),
  ("2015-Jul-8", "0.24"),
  ("2015-Jul-11", "null"),
  ("2015-Jul-12", "null"),
  ("2015-Jul-15", "0.13")
).toDF("datetime", "value")


val df1 = df.withColumn("datetime", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"datetime", "yyyy-MMM-dd")))

df1.filter($"datetime".gt(lit("2017-07-10"))).show // greater than 
df1.filter($"datetime" > (lit("2017-07-10"))).show
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-----+
|           datetime|value|
+-------------------+-----+
|2017-07-10 00:00:00| 0.26|
+-------------------+-----+

df1.filter($"datetime".lt(lit("2017-07-10"))).show  //less than 
df1.filter($"datetime" < (lit("2017-07-10"))).show
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-----+
|           datetime|value|
+-------------------+-----+
|2017-07-09 00:00:00| 0.81|
|2015-07-08 00:00:00| 0.24|
|2015-07-11 00:00:00| null|
|2015-07-12 00:00:00| null|
|2015-07-15 00:00:00| 0.13|
+-------------------+-----+

df1.filter($"datetime".geq(lit("2017-07-10"))).show // greater than equal to 
df1.filter($"datetime" <= (lit("2017-07-10"))).show
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+-----+
|           datetime|value|
+-------------------+-----+
|2017-07-10 00:00:00| 0.26|
+-------------------+-----+
```

Edit: You can also compare `timestamp` by just

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("datetime", unix_timestamp($"datetime", "yyyy-MMM-dd")) //cast to timestamp

df4.filter($"datetime" >= (lit("2017-07-10").cast(TimestampType))).show
//cast "2017-07-10" also to timestamp
```

Hope this helps!